# How to add a new line to the top of the file- OSX&GNU

Tags: macos, sed, perl

i tried the below to add a new line to the top of the file but to no avail

1) seems to work but how do i do it inplace ?
perl -lpe 'BEGIN{print "somestring\n"}' file

2 ) sed -i.bak -e '1i somestring \n' ./file
doesnt add newline in OS X

Comment: `echo > file.new; cat file >> file.new; mv file.new file` if you're okay with not bothering with sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '1{h;s/.*/somestring/;p;g;}' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: doesnt work in OS X

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '1i|somestring' -cx file
```

1. `1` select first line
2. `i` insert new line of text
3. `x` save and close